# NLS initializing Messaging

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using the `NLS.initializeMessages(BUNDLE_NAME, XYZ.class)` to load the constants.

When 'BUNDLE_NAME' and 'XYZ.class' are present in the same project it works, but when it's in a different project it is not working.

Can we use the above API when we have 'BUNDLE_NAME' and 'XYZ.class' in different project?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different project'? Is this another plugin? Is that plugin in the dependencies list of the current plugin?

Comment: Ya this is another plugin project .

Comment: that plugin in the dependencies list of the current plugin -NO

Answer (score 2):

If the class is in another plugin which is not in your plugin's dependency list then you need to know the id of the plugin to load the class.

You would get the class using:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("the plugin id");

Class<?> theClass = bundle.loadClass("the class name");
```

You can then use `NLS.initializeMessages` using the class, **but** the `BUNDLE_NAME` you specify must be loadable by the class loader for `theClass` - which means it must be in the same plugin or one of that plugin's dependencies, it can't be in your plugin.